# joomla 2.5 module development, is module development and component devlopment the same?

Tags: joomla2.5

I was wondering is there some sort of tutorial I'm missing on Joomla 2.5 module development, all I can find is a tutorial on component development. is this the same thing?

But i also look at the the Joomla documentation available and all i can find is Joomla 1.5 development.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context, but my spontaneous answer is no it's not the same thing.

Joomla module development refers to modules. Small "widgets" with lightweight functionality, usually connected to components.

Components are the most advanced "apps" in Joomla. Component development usually refers to development of these apps.

There are also plugins that somehow extend or change the functionality of Joomla.

Joomla extension development, or plain Joomla development, refers to the development of all above.

Comment: This is basically right. The Joomla 1.5 tutorials will work for 2.5, how they are coded hasn't really changed.

Comment: Well actually the manifests are different, so if you want to use parameters for example, then you must make them for 2.5 or both.